# Write dict to csv with integers as keys

Tags: python, database, csv, dictionary, rrd

I have a dict with epoch times as keys. It looks like this:

```
my_dict = {199934234: "val1", 1999234234: "val2"}
```

When trying to write it to a csv, I get the error "iterable expected, not int". There is no problem, however, when using regular keys.

```
import csv

with open('my_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
writer.writerows(my_dict)
```

I want to write it to a csv so that I can load it at a later point again as a dictionary so that I can update it ... and then write it to a csv again. The csv will be accessed by my website later on.

What would be the best solution to do this? In any other case I would use rrd but in this case I do not have irregular update times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function treats the dictionary as an iterable from which it wants to get other iterables (i.e., the rows).

If you iterate a dictionary, you get only the keys:

```
for item in my_dict:
    print(item)
```

```
199934234
1999234234
```

Instead, you want an iterable containing your rows. You can use `my_dict.items()` for that:

```
print(my_dict.items())
```

```
dict_items([(199934234, 'val1'), (1999234234, 'val2')])
```

So:

```
import csv

with open('my_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(my_dict.items())
```

```
# File content.
199934234,val1
1999234234,val2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        writer.writerow([k, v])
```